# how to dynamically change the tabs using javascript function?

Tags: visualforce, html5

In visualforce having two tabs(tab1 and tab2),i need to show defaulty tab1.when call tab2 need to hide tab1 and show tab2.
i am using anchor tag

```
<a href="#tab2"> 


<div class="tabs-container">
                        <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                            <li class="active"><a href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab"> Page1</a></li>
                           <li class="active"><a href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab"> Page2</a></li>
                        </ul>

 <div class="tab-content" id="tabs">
                            <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab-1">
                                <div class="panel-body">

My content

    </div>
        </div>

 <div class="tab-pane" id="tab-2">

 <button id="thisid" data-dismiss="modal" class="close" type="button" ><span aria-hidden="true">×</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>

Mycontent

  </div>
```

defaultly i need to show tab 1 ,when button clicks need to show tab2 and hide tab1.How?

Comment: can you please post the code so that we can check the code and help you..

Comment: <a href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab">
<li class="active"><a href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab"> My Page</a></li>

Comment: <div class="tabs-container">
                        <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                            <li class="active"><a href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab"> Page1</a></li>
                           <li class="active"><a href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab"> Page2</a></li>
                        </ul>

 <div class="tab-content" id="tabs">
                            <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab-1">
                                <div class="panel-body">

My content

 </div>
        </div>

 <div class="tab-pane" id="tab-2">

Mycontent

  </div>

Comment: to be sure, have you look into using Visualforce's apex:tabPanel component, which can help you implement tabs fairly easily. For more details refer https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_tabPanel.htm

Answer (score 1):

> Update - Please see the updated section

You can do `$('.nav-tabs li:nth-child(2) a').tab('show');` to show the second tab and `$('.nav-tabs li:first-child a').hide();` to hide the first tab in the click event of the button as below.

I have created this Bootply link http://www.bootply.com/gYYO3suQiF to test the functionality. Click on "User Details" link in the first tab, it will show the second tab (User Details) and hide the first tab (search). Hope this helps.

**Html tab code**

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a href="#search" data-toggle="tab">Search</a></li>
    <li><a href="#home" data-toggle="tab">User Details</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content" id="tabs">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="search">
      ...Content 1...
      <a id="tab2button">User Details</a>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="home">...Content 2...</div>
</div>
```

**JS code**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.nav-tabs li:eq(0) a').tab('show');

  $('#tab2button').on('click', function() {
    $('.nav-tabs li:nth-child(2) a').tab('show');
    $('.nav-tabs li:first-child a').hide();
  });  
});
```

> Updated solution

You can do this easily by hiding the second tab on page load. Also you can write the functionality for cancel button as below to return to first tab. You can test the code here http://www.bootply.com/yKOjR4YQJY

**JS code**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.nav-tabs li:nth-child(2) a').hide();

  $('#tab2button').on('click', function() {
    $('.nav-tabs li:nth-child(2) a').show();
    $('.nav-tabs li:nth-child(2) a').tab('show');
    $('.nav-tabs li:nth-child(1) a').hide();
    $('.nav-tabs li:nth-child(1) a').tab('hide');
  }); 

  $('#cancelbutton').on('click', function() {
    $('.nav-tabs li:nth-child(1) a').show();
    $('.nav-tabs li:nth-child(1) a').tab('show');
    $('.nav-tabs li:nth-child(2) a').hide();
    $('.nav-tabs li:nth-child(2) a').tab('hide');

  });  
});
```

**Html tab code**

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a href="#search" data-toggle="tab">Search</a></li>
    <li><a href="#home" data-toggle="tab">User Details</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content" id="tabs">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="search">
      ...Content 1...
      <a id="tab2button">User Details</a>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="home">
      ...Content 2...
      <a id="cancelbutton">Cancel</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks its working,but when login in home page it need to show only tab 1 and clicks button need to show tab2 no need to show tab1 and when cancel button clicks in my tab2 content need to show tab1 only no need to show 2.

Comment: Please see my updated solution above. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The question is a little unclear, but I'm assuming when you click a tab you want to hide one and show the other. You could do this via JQuery.

Assuming your HTML is something like this:

```
<ul>
  <li id="tab1">Hello</li>
  <li id="tab2">World</li>
</ul>
```

A basic JQuery Snippet would be like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#tab1").show();
        $("#tab2").hide();

        $("#tab1").click(function() {
            $("#tab1").hide();
            $("#tab2").show();
        });

        $("#tab2").click(function() {
            $("#tab2").hide();
            $("#tab1").show();
        });
    });
</script>
```

This just sets the default show and hide values for list items with the ID of "tab1" and "tab2" then has two functions depending on what you click on to either show or hide the other one.